# How to make <hr> full width?

Tags: html, css

I want to make this `<hr>` so it will stretch the full width, right to the edges of its parent container. I have tried adding margin-left/padding-right to overcome this but it keeps changing when resizing (responsive).

```css
.single-article .article-container-inner {
    background: #f0eded;
    border: 1px solid #c9c7c7;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.single-article hr {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #c9c7c7;
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container single-article">
    <div class="article-container-inner">
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

(also at http://jsfiddle.net/bh2f6/1/)

Is there a better solution for this?

Edit: I can't edit the parent container's padding as that is needed for bunch of other elements.

Comment: This is one of the many examples that show me css is horrible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `width:100%;` on the `<hr />` and the `padding` on the parent were messing things up.  The `<hr />` naturally stretches across the screen and doesn't need `width:100%`, so remove it. Then to compensate for the padding, just add the same negative margin to the `<hr />`.

Change your CSS to this:

```
.single-article hr {
    margin: 30px -20px 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #c9c7c7;
}
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2mXL/)***

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might work...

```
hr {
  padding: 50px 0;
  border: none;

  &:before {
    // full-width divider
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/ZWNwmG

Answer (score 3):

**HR** Secret things, you must know.

When your `horizontal rule` **(hr)** leaves 15px from left and right, probably when you use with `bootstrap`.

```
<hr class="my-hr-line">

.my-hr-line {
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
    height: 2px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Hope it will help many one.

Answer (score 2):

Removing Padding should work for you

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bh2f6/3/)

```
.single-article .article-container-inner {
    background: #f0eded;
    border: 1px solid #c9c7c7;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.single-article hr {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #c9c7c7;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: No I can't edit the parent container's padding as that is needed for bunch of other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh2f6/4/)

just change the padding to `padding: 20px 0;`

Comment: No I can't edit the parent container's padding as that is needed for bunch of other elements

Comment: I understand. Then you should check out Code Maverick's answer. It does the trick with keeping the padding. ;)