# How to make hr tag extend the full width of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a div that has a max width for all its child elements except for hr, so it will extend the full width of the screen. This is what I have right now that's not working:

```
#content :not(hr){
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}

#content hr{
  height: 1px;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}
#container{
  min-height:100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -138px;
}
```

And in the html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">...</div>
      <div id="content">
        ...
        <hr />
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any rules applied for `#container`?

Comment: Only height. #container{
 min-height:100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -138px;
}

Comment: The `hr` element extends to the full width of its container - which is your "content" div's 250px.

Comment: but shouldn't the #content :not(hr) selector affect the elements that are not hr's inside the content div, not the content div itself?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ME8s8/ seems like it works?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, Then it seems like my problem isn't with the code I posted, and something else in the application that I'm overlooking. I have no idea what it could be though. There's no absolute widths specified anywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make <hr> full width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921665/how-to-make-hr-full-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but this may work for what you need:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgWQW/)**

Just make the `hr` wider than the window, and give it enough negative margin to roughly center it. Setting overflow to hidden gets rid of the excess.

CSS:

```
/* new css */
#container {overflow: hidden;}

#content hr {
    width: 1000%;
    margin-left: -500%;
}

/* old css */
#content:not(hr){
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}

#content hr{
  height: 1px;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}
#container{
  min-height:100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -138px;
}
```