# How do I prevent a float image from going next to the HR?

Tags: html, css

I am currently programming a website with many images and HR lines. Unfortunately, some float images with little text besides them end up not being on top of the HR line.

```css
p {
  font-family: serif;
  text-indent: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg/255px-Flag_of_Italy.svg.png" alt="italy flag">
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<hr>
```

[image: here's an image]

Comment: I apologize for not including HTML code. I kept getting errored and the HTML seemed to be the problem. I also remember adding an image, but I do not see it on the post.

Comment: Kept getting errors? Just do three backticks, paste the code, then another 3 backticks

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921785/4935162) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37324953/4935162)

Comment: Your code has no `<hr>` elements at all

Comment: @j08691 I accidentally left it out, but luckily my issue was solved by Yarin_007.

Comment: Before getting to far, is your `img`, `h2` and `p` a self-contained block (wrapped in a `div` or something)? Or does this appear in a larger block of text (e.g. more paragraphs) Curious since using `float` might not be the best approach here if those elements are contained within a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the img tag with div and use flex

```css
p {
  font-family: serif;
  text-indent: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
  width: 200px; 
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 25%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

div {
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-end;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg/255px-Flag_of_Italy.svg.png" alt="italy flag">
</div>  
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Dolor Sit Amet</p>
  <hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe floats take the element out of the dom flow.  use inline-block on the image and adjust the left margin

```css
p {
  font-family: serif;
  text-indent: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:max(calc(100vw - 200px - 30px - 3px),calc(75vw - 45px));  
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 25%;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

div{
border:solid 1px green;}

body,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/03/Flag_of_Italy.svg/255px-Flag_of_Italy.svg.png" alt="italy flag">
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Dolor Sit Amet</p>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: This is dependent on if the elements are wrapped in a cotaining element - see my comment on the question. And if there is a containing element, using `flex` or `grid` would be a better solution. If you run your code, this doesn't solve OPs issue. Changing the `img` to `inline-block` won't position the element **next** to the p/h2/hr tags. Also, using all the math for the margin seems like overkill with the previously mentioned layout methods.

Comment: no, that's not correct.  The elements are obviously wrapped by the body tag and thats sufficient.

Comment: Right..if those are the only elements on the page, but we don't know that - since the first line of the question: _with many images and HR lines_. Also, you might want to combine your two answers.